# UISearchController not responding

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UISearchController on the navigation bar by:

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

and I have

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

Now my problem is first time when I go to the activity having UISearchController, everything works fine. But, in my app from the sidemenu if I go to some activity and then again go to the activity containing UISearchController by pushing to the navigation stack, the search controller does not work. So here is what I am doing:

Let `A` denote the activity containing UISearchController

1. Go to `A`. Everything works fine.
2. Go to any other activity.
3. Go to `A` by pushing it again and not popping back. The UISearchController does not respond. By not responding I mean the searchBar does not respond to touch.

I know I should pop but I cannot for my app. What can be the problem?

Comment: Weird...I'm having the same problem too. Was working before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting definesPresentationContext to NO on the first view controller as soon as you present a new one on.